# Problemas em excluir no MySQL através de MVC 4

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema que não aço a menor ideia do porque está acontecendo e também não consigo resolver. Desenvolvi uma aplicação WEB em MVC 4. Eu consigo incluir e editar novos registros. Mas não quer excluir de jeito nenhum. Não dá nenhum erro. Diz que excluiu com sucesso mas o registro continua no banco. Eu só consigo excluir se eu for direto ao banco. Pela aplicação não.

Verifiquei no método `ExecuteNonQuery` e ele retorna o valor 1, dizendo que uma linha foi alterado no banco de dados. Mas quando vou ao banco o registro continua lá. Parece um bug. Alguém já teve esse problema?

Comment: Poste o trecho de código da sua aplicação que executa o método.

Comment: veja se no teu codigo voce esta chamando o `SaveChanges()`

Comment: O `autocommit` está como `false`?

Comment: Sem postar o código ou o SQL fica difícil poder dar uma ajuda

Comment: um ponto que não aborado nos comments: esse registro tem algum relacionamento externo? e outra coisa, tente fazer um debug step by step e veja iteração do programa..